# SysLog / Stream Review Training Tool - Game - CBT

Tags: educational

I am wondering if anyone is a aware of a training application or a game that I could use to train new staff on multiple concepts from stream / SysLog style data. So basically any text log whether it be windows events, debug code log, or some other text stream data I could
Feed it into this. Right now I do it as a manual exercise and it's time consuming for all involved and I don't just want static short scenarios as that  doesn't simulate real world.

Something I could feed log scenarios into and it would time and score the responses. When I say log scenarios, I mean not just multiple choice, but here is 100 or even a 1000 events review and analyze. Questions would be tagged / classified so ability could be tracked in different areas. Preferably it would also be able to communicate the correct answer after submission.

It doesn't need to be fancy, pretty, or anything like that. I know a couple ways I could write one myself, but before reinventing the wheel thought In would ask if there is anything out there already.

Question Styles

1. Simple multiple choice or multiple selection
2. Identify the key events of the described scenario, could be a couple dozen events.
3. Differentiate root cause event from consequence events
4. Describe what just happened
5. Based on X information filter out the noise, such as click on the event.